Remove spacing after \right) if punctuation follows
I am adding puntuctuation to my equations such as
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    abc.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \left(abc\right).
\end{align}

% Update:
Here, the spacing between the parentheses is ok:
\begin{align}
    \left(abc\right)\left(def\right)
\end{align}

And here, the spacing between the parentheses is ok, but the final spacing before the dot is not
\begin{align}
    \left(abc\right)\left(def\right).
\end{align}

Intended result is similar to:
\begin{align}
    \left(abc\right)\left(def\right)\!.
\end{align}

\end{document}

Clearly, in the generated PDF, the spacing in the two equations above is uneven: There is more space after \right) than simply abc:

How can I automatically fix this spacing? I know I could manually insert \! before the dot, but that gets tedious and I might miss some instances. Also, it is not enough to simply redefine \right) to leave out the space because if it appears inside an equation it should be kept. I want to keep this space.

See also Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?.  Note that the only result of \left/\right in this case is the spacing that you don't want.  So a larger question would be if you really need this in the first place, and if so, what is it you are enclosing.  You can often get a better result manually sizing the fences.

the only affect of left-right here is to add the bad space so just not using it is the best option.

I added a clarification: I think the space is ok if it occurs inside of an equation. I just - for now - want to remove it if it is the last thing before the punctuation.

I'm confused about your distinction of "inside an equation".  I would say {align*} is an equation, so your example is inside an equation.  Could you explain that a bit?

Ok, let me add another example

If the delimiters don't actually grow, you don't need \left and \right. If they really must grow, probably you want that space.

@egreg I want that space everywhere and I want them to grow. I just dont want that particular space before the punctuation.

@HerpDerpington Why using \left(abc\right) to begin with? It does nothing else than adding the unwanted space.

@egreg In this simplified example, you can of course just change it, but I have  macros containing \left and \right pairs which may appear in the center of the equation or as the last part before the punctuation.

So it's not whether the \left/\right is in an equation that matters, it's that you want the space to be there unless it precedes a comma.  Regarding everyone saying you shouldn't use \left/\right in this example and you saying you have other macros: could you give us an example where you think \left/\right is necessary?

You can try with the mleftright package.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    abc.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \left(abc\right).
\end{align}


\begin{align}
    \mleft(abc\mright).
\end{align}

\end{document}



Also include   \bigl(abc\bigr).
